# Where can I find default Microsoft fonts Calibri, Cambria?

Tags: macos, ms-office, font, font-book

If I want to test or use default Microsoft fonts on my Mac, and I own a post-2006 copy of Windows or Office, I believe I can legally use Calibri and Cambria although IANAL. This would be especially helpful when collaborating with colleagues using Office products like Word, Excel, and PowerPoint. Right now, I get a warning like: "Calibri not found. Trebuchet MS used instead." Where can I find them?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

To find and install default Microsoft fonts on a Mac:

1. Navigate [HERE](https://www.rmtweb.co.uk/calibri-and-cambria-fonts-for-mac) in your browser.
2. Download the .ZIP file.
3. Unzip it (double-click it).
4. Open the folder that appears.
5. Select all the .TTF files inside the folder.
6. With the files selected, right-click.
7. From the pop-up menu, choose "open with → Font Book".
8. Click "Install Font" for each font.

*Note:* Changes to fonts take effect when an application is opened or a user logs in to the account or computer on which the changes occurred, see [support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201722).

Comment: Yes, site seems to be dead: TBH, this wasn't a Microsoft affiliated site, but just some random's guy's pages; and they were old versions of the fonts. Shouldn't be anyone first choice.

Answer (score 40):

If you have local Microsoft Word installation, say in `/Applications`, you can find the bundled fonts in the locations below:

- `/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts`
- `/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts` (for earlier versions of Microsoft Office)

The same should apply to other Office applications as well. Then you can copy the fonts to:

```
~/Library/Fonts
```

BTW, in Finder, there's **Go > Go To Folder...(⇧⌘G)**, which can be used to quickly navigate to a specific location.

Comment: Under Mojave, the folder is called DFonts, but otherwise, everything works the same.

This solution has the advantage, that you get many more fonts, including CambriaMath.

Answer (score 17):

If you use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), try the [homebrew-fonts-nonfree tap](https://github.com/colindean/homebrew-fonts-nonfree)

Answer (score 10):

## Use the official Fonts distributed by Microsoft

If you have installed any Microsoft product, there is a chance you already have all Microsoft Fonts in your Mac.

For instance, the path to the fonts of MS Word is:
`"/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts"`
In general:
`"/Applications/some_ms_app/Contents/Resources/Fonts"`

Using the Terminal app, you can copy any font to your font folder: `~/Library/Fonts`

Below are the step-by-step instructions in case you are not familiar with using the terminal:

1. Open Finder and go to the Applications Folder (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Locate MS Word or MS Excel or MS PowerPoint.
3. Right-click and select `Show Package Content`.
4. In Finder navigate through `Contents/Resources/Fonts`.
   You will see all the installed MS Fonts.
5. Drag and Drop (press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key) the desired fonts to your Desktop (or any other user folder).
   You must press the option key to create a copy of the fonts and not a link.
6. Select (in your Desktop) the fonts to install. Right-click and then `Open`.
   The "Font Book" Application will check the fonts and it will probably give you some warnings.
7. Select the fonts in Font Book app and click Install.
8. Delete the extra copies you have in the Desktop.

Do not try to install right from the application package or you will receive a fatal error. That is why in 5. you must make a copy to some user folder (ex. your Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

MS Office Cloud Fonts may be found in a path something like:

`~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/FontCache/4/CloudFonts`